# When and how did the Embecovirus acquire hemagglutinin esterase?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, molecular-evolution, influenza

The *Embecovirus* is different from the rest of *Betacoronavirus* by possessing an additional protein, a [hemagglutinin esterase (HE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemagglutinin_esterase).

There are known similarities between the HE's of different viruses (Coronavirus, Torovirus, and Influenza C), see e.g. [this paper by de Groot (2006)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10719-006-5438-8).

My questions are: How old is this acquisition?
Where does the hemagglutinin esterase come from?

Comment: This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. ——— Where have you looked for answers? Either there are papers reporting on investigation of the evolution of this virus and its acquisition of HE or there aren't; it would improve your question if you reported what you have found (with citations) and why you can't answer at least some of these questions yourself. In fact, if you look at the abstract of the first reference for the wikipedia article you linked to you will find at least one answer.

Comment: Did you look at embecovirus [NS2a](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_048217.1) as well "putative cyclic phosphodiesterase" it is interesting because (at the same location just after ORF1b) there is a 40% similar ORF in Lucheng rat alphacov NC_032730

Comment: @reuns No, not beyond just noticing its existence in the embecovirus. And I noticed that the placement of HE in the Torovirus genome is different from the one in Embecovirus genome.